# How to save worksheets in a csv format while keeping the column separation format?

Tags: vba, excel, csv, save

I'm working on a VBA code that creates multiple sheets from a source (Sheets). I'm trying to save them separately in a CSV format to use them for batch input. However, the requirement is that the saved worksheets must stay in "a column separation format" while in a CSV file.

Here is where I'm at:

```
For i = 0 To nb
If Sheets("PjtDef").Range("A2").Offset(k + i, 0).Value <> "" Then
    Sheets("PjtDef").Range("A2").Offset(k + i, 0).Select
    Sheets("PjtDef").Range("A1", ActiveCell).EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = h
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Worksheets("PjtDef").Activate
    Sheets("PjtDef").Range("A2").Offset(k + i, 0).Select
    Range("A2", ActiveCell).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    h = h + 1
Else: i = nb
End If
Next i

Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xcsvFile As String
For Each Scut In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Scut.Copy
    Name = CurDir & "\" & Scut.Name & ".csv"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Name, _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show how your CSV output is not *in "a column separation format"*

Comment: Do you mean you want to preserve the same delimiter and/or text qualifiers when using the `SaveAs` method?

Answer (score 0):

I have next code working:

```
Sub ExportFile()
Const myDelim As String = "|"

Dim Sheet As Object
Set Sheet = Worksheets
For p = 1 To 2 'you could use sheet.count
Sheet(p).Activate

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long, j As Long
r = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
c = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
Dim myPath As String
myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
Dim myFile As String

filename = ws.name
myFile = myPath & filename & ".extention"
Dim obj As Object
Set obj = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
obj.Type = 2
obj.Charset = "ASCII"
obj.Open
Dim v() As Variant
ReDim v(1 To c)

For i = 3 To r - 1
For j = 1 To c
v(j) = ws.Cells(i, j).Text
Next
obj.WriteText Join(v, myDelim), 1
Next
obj.SaveToFile myFile, 2
End Sub
```

This writes all sheet to a file separating cells in rows by "|"